# Importing Functions from a different C file

Tags: c++, c, function, import

I want to import functions from another file in Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0. How can i do this? I have tried with this as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#import <functions.cpp>
```

where functions.cpp is the file name from where I want to import the functions. But this gives an error: *F:\CC++\Term Project\Dos Plotter\Functiom Plotter.cpp(6) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'Functions.cpp': No such file or directory*

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There are lot of reasons for `fatal error C1083`. Check out this link for various reasons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et4zwx34(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `#import` directive is used with type libraries, often COM or .Net, not C++ source files. For complete details, see [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

In order to include C++ functions from another file, you typically want to use the `#include` directive ([details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx)). This includes the code from the given file during compilation. Most often, you should include a header containing the function prototypes; it is possible to include code files, but not commonly needed or always safe.

To do this, you should provide two files, a header and a source file, for your functions. 
The header will read something like:

```
#pragma once

void Function(int arg);
```

and the source:

```
#include "functions.hpp"

void Function(int arg) { ++arg; }
```

To use this in another file, you do:

```
#include "functions.hpp"

void OtherFunction()
{
    Function(2);
}
```

You should also note that a header should typically be included only once. The MSVC-standard method of guaranteeing this is to add `#pragma once` to the beginning.

**Edit:** and to address the specific error you've posted, which applies to both `#import` and `#include`, the file you're attempting to include must be somewhere within the compiler's search path. In Visual Studio, you should add the necessary path to the project includes (this varies by version, but is typically under project properties -> compiler).

Answer (score 4):

1) Did you mean functions.hpp? C/cpp files should not be `#include`d unless you know very well what you're doing.

2) Add the location of the file to the custom include path in the project properties, or use the `include "foo"` format instead of `include <foo>`

3) Import is undefined in C. You need to separate prototypes and implementations, include-guard the prototypes file, and `#include` the prototypes file.

Answer (score 2):

having the file `functions.cpp` on the same dir, use `include "functions.cpp"` instead

Answer (score 1):

Name the file `imported-function.hpp`, and make sure that it is in the same dir. Or, you could link it to

1. Linux: `/home/uname/appfolder/imported-function.hpp`
2. Windows: `C:\Username\uname\appfolder\imported-function.hpp`
3. ChromeOS: `/home/chronos/u-4e4342ea6b3b92244e7d4753922f0dc7125f4a1d/MyFiles/appfolder/imported-function.hpp`